# The area of the region of the plane bounded by $\max(|x|,|y|) \leq 1$ and $xy \leq 1/2$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, area

The area of the region of the plane bounded by $\max(|x|,|y|) \leq 1$ and $xy \leq 1/2$

Can you explain, in simple terms how the term $\max(|x|,|y|) \leq 1$ represents a square?

The answers below did not give much guidance.

[Area bounded by $\max (|x|, |y|)\leq 1$ and $xy \leq \frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120992/area-bounded-by-max-x-y-leq-1-and-xy-leq-frac12)

[Show that the $\max{ \{ x,y \} }= \frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429622/show-that-the-max-x-y-fracxyx-y2)

Moreover, I also do not understand how can that max term be represented as a function purely in $x$ to perform normal integration thereafter.
There is another answer that uses double integrals. Is there a simpler method? In some solution, the square at the origin is rotated to look like a diamond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand how $\max(|x|,|y|)$ represents a square, consider its complement region. The graph cannot exist in the regions $|x|>1$ and $|y|>1$. Hence the only possibility where it may exist are the intervals:
$$-1\leq x\leq 1$$ and $$-1\leq y \leq 1$$
In these intervals, either $|x|$ or $|y|=1$, hence we must have the perimeter of the $1×1$ square as the graph, as shown in the linked answer.
If you are having trouble understanding the double integration, you may completely skip it. The hyperbola $y=\frac {1}{2x}$ intersects the square at points $(\frac 12, 1)$ and $(1,\frac 12)$. Thus, the area that we need can be represented as:
$$A=B-\int_{\frac 12}^1 \frac {dx}{2x}$$ where $B$ is area bounded by $x$-axis, $y=1$, $x=\frac 12$ and $x=1$. Thus, $B=\frac 12×1=\frac 12$. Thus $A$ can be easily evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for that concise explanation. Nothing more than what was needed.

Comment: Is this a square and not a diamond?

Comment: I changed "compliment" to "complement". Those are two different words. If I say your answer is brilliant, that's a compliment (with an "i"). But here you're writing about a complement (with an "e").

Comment: @MichaelHardy If you know either of the two, you know what the difference is. But still, you got a chance to add $e^1$ somewhere.

Comment: @Michael Hardy I am a phone user, that was auto-correct. I am aware of the difference between the two words.

Comment: @mathx, the expression $max(|x|,|y|)=1$ does not represent a diamond, but a square with edges along the coordinate axes. Think about it, $(1,1)$ is certainly a point on the curve, yet it wouldn't have been included, had we taken a diamond.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Correct. Again, just what was needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To say that $\max\{|x|,|y|\} \le 1$ is the same as saying that **both** $|x|\le1$ and $|y|\le 1.$

$|x|\le1$ is equivaent to $-1\le x\le+1.$

So $-1\le x\le+1$ and $-1\le y\le+1.$

That is a square.